# Unexpected Rebooting of Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: reboot, system

I have been using Ubuntu 18.04 in my PC for past 4 months. Of late my PC is restarting unexpectedly . Kindly help me since I am using the system for high level computations. Unexpected reboot will cause a loss of data

Comment: `journalctl -b -1 -e` will show you the logs leading up to the last crash. `-b -2` will show the one before that, etc. If crash logs seem random (system behaving normally, then CRASH), suspect overheating - is your fan happy? Is your computer full of dust? Is it overheating?