# Unexpected restart of Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: shutdown, cron, fan, syslog

Last few days I have many unexpected reboots of my Ubuntu 18.04.

Visual effects:

– work as usual (docker, intelliJ, firefox)
– unexpected halt
– fans goes crazy
– push restart button
– PC start normally

### LOGS

Based on answers and comments from:

[Unexpected Rebooting of Ubuntu 18.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1140045/unexpected-rebooting-of-ubuntu-18-04)
[Possible cause of unexpected shutdown?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1129359/possible-cause-of-unexpected-shutdown)
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/9819/how-to-find-out-from-the-logs-what-caused-system-shutdown

I did small investigation. In syslog I observe that (yesterday):

```
Jul  8 20:39:20 koziolek-desktop kernel: [19850.577362] usblp 1-2:1.1: usblp2: USB Bidirectional printer dev 10 if 1 alt 0 proto 2 vid 0x04E8 pid 0x346A
Jul  8 20:39:20 koziolek-desktop upowerd[1912]: unhandled action 'bind' on /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-2/1-2:1.1
Jul  8 20:39:20 koziolek-desktop upowerd[1912]: unhandled action 'unbind' on /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-2/1-2:1.1
Jul  8 20:39:20 koziolek-desktop upowerd[1912]: unhandled action 'bind' on /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-2/1-2:1.1
Jul  8 20:40:36 koziolek-desktop indicator-sound[2809]: accounts-service-access.vala:218: unable to sync volume 0,389511 to AccountsService: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.InvalidArgs: Brak interfejsu „com.ubuntu.AccountsService.Sound”
Jul  8 20:40:42 koziolek-desktop indicator-sound[2809]: accounts-service-access.vala:218: unable to sync volume 0,509506 to AccountsService: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.InvalidArgs: Brak interfejsu „com.ubuntu.AccountsService.Sound”
Jul  8 20:40:43 koziolek-desktop indicator-sound[2809]: accounts-service-access.vala:218: unable to sync volume 0,629501 to AccountsService: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.InvalidArgs: Brak interfejsu „com.ubuntu.AccountsService.Sound”
Jul  8 20:45:01 koziolek-desktop CRON[16499]: (root) CMD (command -v debian-sa1 > /dev/null && debian-sa1 1 1)
Jul  8 20:55:01 koziolek-desktop CRON[16638]: (root) CMD (command -v debian-sa1 > /dev/null && debian-sa1 1 1)
Jul  8 21:24:31 koziolek-desktop systemd-modules-load[306]: Inserted module 'lp'
Jul  8 21:24:31 koziolek-desktop systemd-modules-load[306]: Inserted module 'ppdev'
```

Reboot happen at 20:55

And (today)

```
Jul  9 09:54:20 koziolek-desktop compiz[4712]: [07/09/21, 09:54:20:618] info: [API-Q] (T1Z2181B6) noversion-1625817260.615 Flannel users/info is ENQUEUED
Jul  9 09:54:20 koziolek-desktop compiz[4712]: [07/09/21, 09:54:20:618] info: [API-Q] (T1Z2181B6) noversion-1625817260.615 Flannel users/info is ACTIVE
Jul  9 09:54:20 koziolek-desktop compiz[4712]: [07/09/21, 09:54:20:762] info: [API-Q] (T1Z2181B6) noversion-1625817260.615 Flannel users/info is RESOLVED
Jul  9 09:55:01 koziolek-desktop CRON[32133]: (root) CMD (command -v debian-sa1 > /dev/null && debian-sa1 1 1)
Jul  9 09:55:26 koziolek-desktop compiz[4712]: [07/09/21, 09:55:26:176] info: [DND] (T0CBGV69Z) Checking for changes in DND status for the following members: US6JY18JY,U5WFSP48M,UND9VBB5K,U1UNVEE2D,U01BNLCS545,U3LF4KW2H,U2GCQT811,U01D7K4L6DP
Jul  9 09:55:26 koziolek-desktop compiz[4712]: [07/09/21, 09:55:26:177] info: [DND] (T0CBGV69Z) Will check for changes in DND status again in 5 minutes
^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@Jul  9 09:56:15 koziolek-desktop systemd[1]: Starting Flush Journal to Persistent Storage...
Jul  9 09:56:15 koziolek-desktop systemd-modules-load[314]: Inserted module 'lp'
Jul  9 09:56:15 koziolek-desktop systemd[1]: Started Create Static Device Nodes in /dev.
Jul  9 09:56:15 koziolek-desktop systemd[1]: Started Load/Save Random Seed.
Jul  9 09:56:15 koziolek-desktop systemd[1]: Starting udev Kernel Device Manager...
Jul  9 09:56:15 koziolek-desktop systemd-modules-load[314]: Inserted module 'ppdev'
```

Reboot happen at 09:55

In `last -x | tac`:

```
koziolek :1           :1               Thu Jul  8 15:08 - crash  (06:15)
runlevel (to lvl 5)   4.15.0-147-gener Thu Jul  8 15:09 - 21:25  (06:15)
koziolek pts/2        tmux(9597).%0    Thu Jul  8 15:09 - crash  (06:15)
koziolek pts/3        tmux(9597).%1    Thu Jul  8 19:15 - crash  (02:08)
reboot   system boot  4.15.0-147-gener Thu Jul  8 21:24   still running
runlevel (to lvl 5)   4.15.0-147-gener Thu Jul  8 21:25 - 09:56  (12:31)
koziolek :1           :1               Thu Jul  8 21:28 - crash  (12:27)
koziolek pts/2        tmux(17801).%0   Thu Jul  8 21:29 - crash  (12:26)
reboot   system boot  4.15.0-147-gener Fri Jul  9 09:56   still running
koziolek :1           :1               Fri Jul  9 09:56   still logged in
runlevel (to lvl 5)   4.15.0-147-gener Fri Jul  9 09:56   still running
koziolek pts/2        tmux(10152).%0   Fri Jul  9 09:57   still logged in
```

in `journalctl -b -1 -e`:

```
lip 09 09:54:20 koziolek-desktop compiz[4712]: [07/09/21, 09:54:20:762] info: [API-Q] (T1Z2181B6) noversion-1625817260.615 Flannel users/info is RESOLVED
lip 09 09:55:01 koziolek-desktop CRON[32132]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
lip 09 09:55:01 koziolek-desktop CRON[32133]: (root) CMD (command -v debian-sa1 > /dev/null && debian-sa1 1 1)
lip 09 09:55:01 koziolek-desktop CRON[32132]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
lip 09 09:55:26 koziolek-desktop compiz[4712]: [07/09/21, 09:55:26:176] info: [DND] (T0CBGV69Z) Checking for changes in DND status for the following members: US6JY18JY,U5WFSP48M,UND9VBB5K,U1UNVEE2D,U01BNLCS545,U
lip 09 09:55:26 koziolek-desktop compiz[4712]: [07/09/21, 09:55:26:177] info: [DND] (T0CBGV69Z) Will check for changes in DND status again in 5 minutes
```

### Suspicion

First was too high temperature. Summer, could happen. But I work in room where I have no more than 20°C and sensors never show more than 45°C (on both CPU and GPU).

Second is `CMD (command -v debian-sa1 > /dev/null && debian-sa1 1 1)` and that all restarts happen at HH:55.

Then I found [Machine stops suddenly, Only hard reset can help](https://askubuntu.com/questions/304321/machine-stops-suddenly-only-hard-reset-can-help)

but I have 48GB of RAM and that was very old Ubuntu so it should not be a reason.

### Questions

It is simple – Why my PC reboot? Is there any other checks/wokr that I could do to find the reason?

ps. `uname -a`:

`Linux koziolek-desktop 4.15.0-147-generic #151-Ubuntu SMP Fri Jun 18 19:21:19 UTC 2021 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`

Comment: Are you intentionally running debian-sa1 with cron? Looks like you have one or more instances of a cron task to run it on an hourly basis. I’d start by disabling those tasks unless you have a particular reason to run them

Comment: Sudden poweroff is a motherboard feature, not an Ubuntu feature. Nothing useful logged also points toward a hardware fault. Might be thermal, might be a dying power supply.

Comment: Seeing a similar issue in ubuntu 22.04 on asus rog m16.  Same last journal message, "Checking for changes in DND status for the following members".  I thought it might be thermal related, but I have my PC on a FAN stand to keep it cool, and still see periodic restarts.